Deriving the EFT from a Lagrangian with a Right-Handed Neutrino Field
I am working through the MIT EFT course, and I am having trouble with one of the problems. The task is to find the effective field theory (EFT) from the most general Lagrangian with a right-handed neutrino field. The Lagrangian is given by:
$\mathcal{L}_N = i \overline{N} \not\partial N - \frac{M}{2} \overline{N}N^c - \frac{M}{2} \overline{N^c} N + g (\overline{N}H_i \epsilon^{ij} L_j + H_i^*\epsilon^{ij} \overline{L_j} N)$
The solution provided involves rewriting the Lagrangian in terms of the physical field $n=N+N^c$, so that the Lagrangian becomes:
$\mathcal{L}_N = \frac{1}{2}\overline{n} (i \not\partial - M) n + g (\overline{n}H_i \epsilon^{ij} L_j + H_i^*\epsilon^{ij} \overline{L_j} n)$
After some algebraic steps using properties like $\overline{\psi} \xi = \overline{\xi^c} \psi^c$ and $n^c = n$, the Lagrangian is rewritten as:
$\mathcal{L}_N = \frac{1}{2}\overline{n} (i \not\partial - M) n + g \overline{n} (H_i \epsilon^{ij} L_j + H_i^*\epsilon^{ij} L^c_j)$
Then, the equation of motion (EoM) for $\overline{n}$ is computed:
$0 = \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}_N}{\delta \overline{n}} = (i \not\partial - M) n + g (H_i \epsilon^{ij} L_j + H_i^*\epsilon^{ij} L^c_j)$
And thus,
$n = -\frac{g}{(i \not\partial - M)}(H_i \epsilon^{ij} L_j + H_i^*\epsilon^{ij} L^c_j)$
And finally substituted into the full Lagrangian to obtain the EFT Lagrangian.
My questions are:

When deriving the EoM, shouldn't $n$ and $\overline{n}$ be treated as independent fields? If so, why does the factor $1/2$ disappear when taking the derivative wrt $\overline{n}$? Does the fact that $n = n^c = C\overline{n}^T$ imply that we cannot treat them as independent?

The solution substitutes $n$ back into the full Lagrangian to derive the EFT. However, usually when substituting the EoM back into the Lagrangian, it vanishes. This would be the case here if $n$ and $\overline{n}$ were independent fields. In general, do we need to substitute the EoM back to the full Lagrangian? Or only to the interaction terms?

I understand that integrating out a heavy field is more rigorously done using path integrals and that using the EoM is typically a tree-level approximation. How would I approach solving this exercise using the path integral formalism?



To answer your second question, see the answer for this question here: Gross-Neveu model as effective theory for Yukawa model.  Also, your third question is partially answered there also (at least how to get started since it does not involve any SU(2) indices or stuff like that).
